# Flatten a pair of matrices within a list of matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, iteration

I have a list of matrices, which I think is better to give an example using the code.

```
matlist =
{
   {
      {
         {  1.5,     0, 1},
         {  1.5,  0.42, 0}, 
         { 1.73,  0.42, 2}, 
         { 2.06,  0.42, 0},
         {2.305, 0.535, 0}, 
         { 2.55,  0.65, 2},
         { 2.55,  1.09, 0},
         { 2.55,  6.64, 1},
         { 1.59,  6.64, 2},
      }, 
      {
         {-0.11,  -2.4, 1},
         {-0.11, -1.93, 0},
         {-0.02, -1.93, 2}, 
         { 0.41, -1.93, 0},
         { 0.71,-1.765, 0}, 
         { 1.01,  -1.6, 2}, 
         { 1.17,  -1.2, 0},
         { 1.33,  -0.8, 2}, 
         { 1.33, -0.09, 0},
         { 1.33,    3., 1}, 
         { 1.33,    6., 2}, 
         { 1.33,  6.48, 0},
         {1.085,   6.6, 0},
         { 0.84,  6.72, 2}, 
         { 0.51,  6.72, 0}, 
         { 0.38,  6.72, 1},
         { 0.38,  7.14, 0},
      }
   },
   {
      { 3.29,  7.14, 0},
      { 3.29,  6.72, 0},
      { 3.16,  6.72, 2},
      { 2.82,  6.72, 0}, 
      { 2.58,   6.6, 0}, 
      { 2.34,  6.48, 2}, 
      { 2.34,    6., 0},
      { 2.34,    3., 1}, 
      { 2.34, -0.09, 2}, 
      { 2.34, -0.98, 0},
      {2.035, -1.48, 0}, 
      { 1.73, -1.99, 2},
      {1.215, -2.19, 0},
      {  0.7,  -2.4, 2},
      { 0.06, - 2.4, 0}
   }
}
```

I want to be able to combine the first two matrices into a single matrix (the second in rows added to the first) perhaps using `Flatten` so that the result looks like this:

```
{
   {
      {  1.5,     0, 1},
      {  1.5,  0.42, 0}, 
      { 1.73,  0.42, 2}, 
      { 2.06,  0.42, 0},
      {2.305, 0.535, 0}, 
      { 2.55,  0.65, 2},
      { 2.55,  1.09, 0},
      { 2.55,  6.64, 1},
      { 1.59,  6.64, 2},
      {-0.11,  -2.4, 1},
      {-0.11, -1.93, 0},
      {-0.02, -1.93, 2}, 
      { 0.41, -1.93, 0},
      { 0.71,-1.765, 0}, 
      { 1.01,  -1.6, 2}, 
      { 1.17,  -1.2, 0},
      { 1.33,  -0.8, 2}, 
      { 1.33, -0.09, 0},
      { 1.33,    3., 1}, 
      { 1.33,    6., 2}, 
      { 1.33,  6.48, 0},
      {1.085,   6.6, 0},
      { 0.84,  6.72, 2}, 
      { 0.51,  6.72, 0}, 
      { 0.38,  6.72, 1},
      { 0.38,  7.14, 0},
   },
   {
      { 3.29,  7.14, 0},
      { 3.29,  6.72, 0},
      { 3.16,  6.72, 2},
      { 2.82,  6.72, 0}, 
      { 2.58,   6.6, 0}, 
      { 2.34,  6.48, 2}, 
      { 2.34,    6., 0},
      { 2.34,    3., 1}, 
      { 2.34, -0.09, 2}, 
      { 2.34, -0.98, 0},
      {2.035, -1.48, 0}, 
      { 1.73, -1.99, 2},
      {1.215, -2.19, 0},
      {  0.7,  -2.4, 2},
      { 0.06, - 2.4, 0}
   }
}
```

If possible I would like this to be done for any combined list of matrices and pairs of matrices, so that for example a list of matrices `{A,{B,C},{D,E},F,G,{H,I}}` could theoretically become `{A,BC,DE,F,G,HI}` where the double letters are the flattened matrices.

Comment: `MapAt[Catenate, matlist, {1}]`, Also note that Mathematica doesn't support tailing comma.

Comment: I would like it more with a general solution, where I might not know the index. If the order in ```matlist``` were flipped, I would like what ever function to still produce the same result.

Comment: I found this to work okay, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution:
```Table[If[ArrayDepth[matlist][[ind]]==3,Flatten[matlist[[ind]],1],matlist[[ind]]],{ind,1,Length[matlist]}]```